# converting iOS/Android groovy gradle file to kotlin - getBinary, getProperty (+ literal attributes)?

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin, multiplatform, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to convert the gradle files for a project with both iOS and Android targets from groovy

I have these two lines in the groovy file

```
    val srcFile = kotlin.targets."$target".compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)}
    val targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
```

The first challenge is the "$targets" as an attribute.  Target is property which is a string, so this is like using a string as an attribute name.  But I would expect `targets` is a map, and so is compilations?

```
    val srcFile = kotlin.targets[target].compilations[main].getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)}
    val targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
```

seems to be valid kotlin, so I am assuming the groovy is like js and objects and maps can both be accessed by [] and . notations.   Assuming this is correct, the problem becomes that both `getBinary` and `getProperty` are unkown.

Any help with this appreciated.

For reference, these lines are part of a task:

```
task("copyFramework") {
    val buildType:String = project.findProperty("kotlin.build.type") as String??: "DEBUG"
    val target:String = project.findProperty("kotlin.target")as String? ?: "ios"
    dependsOn("link${buildType.toLowerCase().capitalize()}Framework${target.capitalize()}")

    doLast {
        val srcFile = kotlin.targets[target].compilations["main"].getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)
        val targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
        copy {
            from(srcFile.parent)
            into(targetDir)
            include("app.framework/**")
            include("app.framework.dSYM")
        }
    }
```

converted (so far) from groovy:

```
task copyFramework {
    def buildType = project.findProperty("kotlin.build.type") ?: "DEBUG"
    def target = project.findProperty("kotlin.target") ?: "ios"
    dependsOn "link${buildType.toLowerCase().capitalize()}Framework${target.capitalize()}"

    doLast {
        def srcFile = kotlin.targets."$target".compilations.main.getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)
        def targetDir = getProperty("configuration.build.dir")
        copy {
            from srcFile.parent
            into targetDir
            include 'app.framework/**'
            include 'app.framework.dSYM'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `kotlin` variable defined?

Comment: I believe `koltin` is defined by the kotlin multiplatform plugin – https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you managed to sole it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it requires type casting:

```
val srcFile = (kotlin.targets[target] as KotlinNativeTarget).compilations["main"].getBinary("FRAMEWORK", buildType)
```